# How can I get certain parameters of tweets to save them into a file using json.stringify? (Method I use works for Stream but not for GET)

Tags: json, node.js, twitter

I am trying to save into a file only user @screen_name and text of the tweet I get using the Twitter API and I cant find any documentation for this on Twitter API website or json.strinigify docs. The code I am using, which doesn't really work with GET for some reason, is this (I cant find anything related to solving my problem in Google):

```
var params = {q: '@Avengers, count: 1, include_rts: 1};
client.get('search/tweets', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets);
    fs.appendFile("tweet.txt", JSON.stringify(tweets.text), function (err) {
    //user.name or .text doesn't work in GET and I am trying to find the methods
    //that work for GET 
        if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Saved!');
        }); 
    }
});
```

When I use something similar using Stream, it does work and it saves both the username that posted the tweet and the text of the tweet (which is what I need). My problem here is that stream doesn't have any method to get tweets with the user @screen_name, so I proceded to use GET method. My stream code for doing this is below:

```
var stream = client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'Avengers'});
    stream.on('data', function(event) {
        console.log("Tweeted by ::::>>>" + event.user.name + " ::::>>> " +  "Tweet is :::>>>> " + event.text + " ::::>>>");
        fs.appendFile("tweet.txt", JSON.stringify(event.user.name+' ////////'+event.text)+"\n", function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
    });
});
```

My result with the GET method is a big mess of parameters I don't need when it saves in the file:

```
 "statuses": [
  {
   "created_at": "Sun Sep 23 05:03:17 +0000 2018",
   "id": 1043727480572522500,
   "id_str": "1043727480572522496",
   "text": "@Avengers Gamora, Dr Strange and Vision all made comment about dying before given up Stones in 1st 45 minutes. Gett… --------OtAEPXbih4",
   "truncated": true,
   "entities": {
    "hashtags": [],
    "symbols": [],
    "user_mentions": [
     {
      "screen_name": "Avengers",
      "name": "The Avengers",
      "id": 393852070,
      "id_str": "393852070",
      "indices": [
       0,
       9
      ]
     }
    ],
    "urls": [
     {
      "url": "--------OtAEPXbih4",
      "expanded_url": "--------i/web/status/1043727480572522496",
      "display_url": "twitter.com/i/web/status/1…",
      "indices": [
       117,
       140
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "metadata": {
    "iso_language_code": "en",
    "result_type": "recent"
   },
   "source": "<a href=\"--------#!/download/ipad\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPad</a>",
   "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id": 393852070,
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "393852070",
   "in_reply_to_screen_name": "Avengers",
   "user": {
    "id": 1558865406,
    "id_str": "1558865406",
    "name": "john sabo",
    "screen_name": "saybow1969",
    "location": "",
    "description": "",
    "url": null,
    "entities": {
     "description": {
      "urls": []
     }
    },
    "protected": false,
    "followers_count": 52,
    "friends_count": 397,
    "listed_count": 5,
    "created_at": "Sun Jun 30 20:40:04 +0000 2013",
    "favourites_count": 680,
    "utc_offset": null,
    "time_zone": null,
    "geo_enabled": true,
    "verified": false,
    "statuses_count": 24062,
    "lang": "en",
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "is_translator": false,
    "is_translation_enabled": false,
    "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
    "profile_background_image_url": "----://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
    "profile_background_image_url_----": "----://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_image_url": "----://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/825511373396439040/zZf_Z9Hu_normal.jpg",
    "profile_image_url_----": "----://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/825511373396439040/zZf_Z9Hu_normal.jpg",
    "profile_banner_url": "----://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1558865406/1486454716",
    "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "has_extended_profile": false,
    "default_profile": true,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "following": false,
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "notifications": false,
    "translator_type": "none"
   },
   "geo": null,
   "coordinates": null,
   "place": null,
   "contributors": null,
   "is_quote_status": false,
   "retweet_count": 0,
   "favorite_count": 0,
   "favorited": false,
   "retweeted": false,
   "lang": "en"
  }
 ],
 "search_metadata": {
  "completed_in": 0.015,
  "max_id": 1043727480572522500,
  "max_id_str": "1043727480572522496",
  "next_results": "?max_id=1043727480572522495&q=%40Avengers&count=1&include_entities=1",
  "query": "%40Avengers",
  "refresh_url": "?since_id=1043727480572522496&q=%40Avengers&include_entities=1",
  "count": 1,
  "since_id": 0,
  "since_id_str": "0"
 }
}
```

My Stream method does this correctly but my GET doesn't, and this is what my stream gives me:

```
"Trash Flaten ////////@lliejuve @lliejuve on current tv it has to be the voice actor for Thor in Disney's Avengers Assemble. So o respect…
```

As you can see, Stream gives me the user @screen_name and the text of the tweet which is what I need, but in the GET method user.name and .text just doesnt do it.

Comment: The save is working with GET, right? You are getting the entire JSON in the file, is that the issue?

Comment: @Royson Yes, exactly! With stream it gets rid of that big mess using user.name and .text but GET gives me the whole file because user.name and .text doesn't work in GET and I only want those 2 things I mentioned.

Comment: This is because tweets contains property statuses as an array and there is no text or user property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var params = {q: '@Avengers, count: 1, include_rts: 1};
client.get('search/tweets', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets);
    fs.appendFile("tweet.txt", JSON.stringify(tweets.statuses[0].text), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Saved!');
        }); 
    }
});
```

Try this above change. It should work.

Comment: Thx! It works, what you mentioned of statuses being an array makes a lot of sense. I debugged my file and noticed that GET method gives me an array for the tweet and Stream doesn't.

Comment: @EAlexisMT FYI, The difference in object is not caused by the GET and stream but rather due to the different paths 'search/tweets' and 'statuses/filter'. Hope this helps you in future